# SQL Join in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns

- product_types
- brand_ids

I need the **brand_ids** A and B, but not C

In this table, can have multiple records with the same product_type, but with different brand_ids.

Could it be the need of a INNER SELF JOIN? or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: if you need database help, send sample data and expected results.  that is the easiest way to help you because i dont know what you are asking.

Comment: Did you mean `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.product_type
FROM product_table A
JOIN product_table B ON A.product_type = B.product_type
LEFT JOIN product_table C ON A.product_type = C.product_type
                         AND c.brand_id = 'C'
WHERE A.brand_id = 'A'
  AND B.brand_id = 'B'
  AND c.brand_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `(PRODUCT_TYPE, BRAND_ID)` is a unique key of your table.

Here's one method to do what I think you are after:

```
SELECT product_type FROM product_table
  WHERE brand_id IN ('A','B')
  GROUP BY product_type
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
MINUS
SELECT product_type FROM product_table
  WHERE brand_id IN ('C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT a.product_type
FROM
(
    SELECT product_type 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE brand_id IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY product_type
) a
LEFT JOIN tbl b ON a.product_type = b.product_type AND b.brand_id = 'C'
WHERE b.brand_id IS NULL
```